# What does 면서 있다 mean in this case?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does `면서 있다` mean in this case? 
Why not just `TV를 봐` or `TV를 보고 있어`?

> 가 : 뭐하고있냐? 
>   나 : 그냥 TV를 보면서 있지

Answer (score 1):

> 가: 뭐 하고 있냐? (What are you doing?)
>
> 나: 그냥 TV를 보면서 있지. (I'm here just watching TV.)

This question–answer pair shows their **styles**. We cannot judge whether these sentences are correct. Obviously,

> 가: 지금 뭐 해? (What are you doing right now?)
>
> 나: TV 봐. (I'm watching TV.)

is simpler and clearer. I prefer to say something in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure, but I suspect that the 면서 있지 implies that the speaker is just haphazardly watching TV with no particular interest in what he or she is watching; just lying about, passing time, watching whatever.